# Should I switch to coding my extension with boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, boilerplate

I am creating an extension for the first time and I saw some extensions on github [like this one](https://github.com/samueljun/tomato-clock) and noticed that he coded his extension using a boilerplate. To be honest, I didn't even knew that you could use boilerplates (a friend told me), it's my first time reading about it.

I wonder if I should clone some github repository and copy paste my files and work in it. I see that there are some boilerplates that give cross-browser support for your extension.

I am a little bit confused as I don't know if this is the right way to do it. Right now I don't need something huge for my extension because it's a simple one and I'm learning how things work (kind of new to webdev). I might want to add some google analytics to my extension later.

Would you advise me to use some boilerplate? To me it looks tidy but I can't understand most of the stuff that's happening around, would be difficult to modify some files.

Also, most of the boilerplates are for react, is there one that is like the most basic one for vanillaJS... like how can I find the one that is used in the repo link on top of the post?

Comment: "*I am creating an extension*" - an extension to what?

Comment: @Bergi chrome extension*